# Достать инфу из бд по message.text

Tags: python, sqlite3

Уважаемые, помогите пожалуйста, достать инфу из бд по запросу==message.text.

```
@bot.message_handler()
def send_query(message):
    cur.execute("DROP table IF EXISTS tovarniye_ostatki")
    cur.execute("CREATE virtual table IF NOT EXISTS tovarniye_ostatki USING FTS5 
    (nazvaniye_tovara,ostatok_tovara)")
    with open ("domstroy.csv",'r', encoding="utf8",) as file:
        for row in file:   
            cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tovarniye_ostatki VALUES 
          (?,?)",row.split(";"),)
        db.commit()
    cur.execute("SELECT ostatok_tovara, nazvaniye_tovara  FROM  tovarniye_ostatki WHERE 
    nazvaniye_tovara MATCH (?)",(message.text,))
    db.close()
```

Когда юзер вводить запрос(message.text), например, "travertin"
Бот должен вытащить все товары которые включают этот текст, например, "travertin vnutrenniy", "cvetnoy travertin", "travertin fasad" с остатками товара и так далее.

```
структура бд:

Nazvanie_tovara    Ostatok_tovara
Imulsiya 20kg        5
Travertin 15kg      45
cvetnoy travertin   13.5
travertin fasad     74  
kraska 5kg          10
```

"csv" файл импортируется в бд.

Comment: А в чем проблема? Что внутри файла? Как примерно устроена бд? Не совсем понятно что требуется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько понял, Вы используете библиотеку sqlite3?

Попробуйте следующее, чтобы получить Ваши данные:

```
@bot.message_handler()
def send_query(message):
    cur.execute("DROP table IF EXISTS tovarniye_ostatki")
    cur.execute("CREATE virtual table IF NOT EXISTS tovarniye_ostatki USING FTS5 
    (nazvaniye_tovara,ostatok_tovara)")
    with open ("domstroy.csv",'r', encoding="utf8",) as file:
        for row in file:   
            cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tovarniye_ostatki VALUES 
          (?,?)",row.split(";"),)
        db.commit()
    result_query = cur.execute("SELECT ostatok_tovara, nazvaniye_tovara  FROM  tovarniye_ostatki WHERE 
    nazvaniye_tovara MATCH (?)",(message.text,))
    result = result_query.fetchall()
    print(result)
    db.close()
```

Подробнее про получение данных после метода execute можно почитать в документации:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone

Comment: норм работает, но мне надо результат запроса отправить в бот.

Comment: я добавила строку bot.send_message(message.chat.id, result), но в бот отправляется количество найденных строк. А надо список товаров и их остатки.
Спасибо.

Comment: Нужно преобразовать список, который получаем с помощью fetchall в строку, тогда эту строку можно отправить через bot.send_message. Можно пройтись по списку и после прохождения будет создана наша строка

Comment: data = ' '.join(str(x) for x in result);


bot.send_message(data, ...)